# Migrating from Ant to gradle build android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an existing ANT build project build using Intelli J . I want to migrate it to Gradle build .What to do?
I have Android studio also.

Comment: see this link   https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is asked several times on Stack overflow.
Here's the answer anyways since you appear to be beginner.

It can be easily done using android studio.
1)Set up Android Studio. 2) On home screen select import non gradle project. 3)It will take some time to restructure your project 4) IF you find some missing dependencies, add them from Maven.
5) Run the code and you are done

Comment: Sorry i didnt searched correctly; @Android learner thanx for understanding

Comment: Happens, everyone is a beginner someday. Advice: Research Stack overflow a bit before answering